# Javascript Sort Array by Value

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an AJAX call returning JSON like...

```
{
  490: "A",
  675: "B",
  491: "C",
  520: "D",
  681: "E",
  679: "F",
  538: "G"    
}
```

I then have it appending to a `select` using:

```
var output = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$.each(output, function(key, value) {
    $el.append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value", key).text(value));
});
```

I'd like to sort by the value so the output is `A,B,C,D...` as right now it just reads in order of the key.

**Here's the kicker** - seems to work fine in Firefox, not in Chrome.

Comment: have you checked the console in chrome to see what error if any you are getting?

Comment: Yeah, no errors in FF or Chrome

Comment: What works fine in Firefox but not Chrome? Appending the output? Some sorting algorithm you're not showing us?

Comment: have you tried debugging in any way? for example outputting anything at any stage apart from just before and after the sort?

Comment: Are you able to sort it server-side?

Comment: I have it sorting server-side, and that's (currently) the only sort (ORDER BY 'name')

Comment: By the way, here's a sample in chrome showing that it does not keep the current sort order. http://jsfiddle.net/82BSm/2/ And here it is if you make it an array: http://jsfiddle.net/82BSm/1/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

first convert it into array, sort it, then create html. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3eUX/)

```
var output = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var temp = [];

$.each(output, function(key, value) {
    temp.push({v:value, k: key});
});
temp.sort(function(a,b){
   if(a.v > b.v){ return 1}
    if(a.v < b.v){ return -1}
      return 0;
});
$.each(temp, function(key, obj) {

$el.append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value", obj.k).text(obj.v));
});
```

Comment: Why would you sort it with javascript if you are already sorting it with SQL? You're treating the symptoms instead of fixing the problem.

Comment: What happens when another sort is added, or changed completely.

Comment: @KevinB He has not mentioned about server side sorting in question. Am I missing something?

Comment: It was mentioned in a comment *"I have it sorting server-side, and that's (currently) the only sort (ORDER BY 'name')"* and this too: *"Yeah, the data I'm getting is 600 entries and a whole mess of information"*

Comment: @KevinB Even it sorted in server side it will not side effect here.

Comment: @KevinB It would require a different JSON response. Within the given restriction (as it is assumed to be), it must be sorted again as it rides in via an "object".

Comment: @Sushil You also have 1 unnecessary each loop.  You can just push the options in the array.. sort.. the append all at once

Comment: @wirey, I think it is not possible as temp contains object so I cant use join. and second option: if i save option html in temp item object. then again I have to iterate it. third is possible to create html and push it in temp and compare html itself but I don.t think this is good way.

Comment: You just have to sort on the text().. just how you are sorting on the value right now http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/SvkRx/

Comment: Yes, I did mention this solution in my last comment. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Objects cannot be sorted. Try returning your JSON as an array to ensure it stays in the exact order that you return them in:

```
[
  {"id":490,"name":"A"},
  {"id":675,"name":"B"},
  {"id":491,"name":"C"},
  {"id":520,"name":"D"},
  {"id":681,"name":"E"},
  {"id":679,"name":"F"},
  {"id":538,"name":"G"}
]
```

Here's a fiddle with the original: http://jsfiddle.net/82BSm/2/ and changing to an array: http://jsfiddle.net/82BSm/1/

*Updated per pst's comment*

You could of course make the json response size smaller by separating the column names ("id" and "name") from the data and making it an array of arrays.

Comment: I don't think this is really a propblem since it seems the order in which it is returned is nothing to do with the order in which it should be displayed.  It seems the OP wishes to sort a set of unsorted values, in which case the object he returned will do the job just fine.  **I may be completely wrong though**

Comment: @JonTaylor I agree, though i suspect the data he's actually using may not be what he has posted.

Comment: Yeah, the data I'm getting is 600 entries and a whole mess of information. I posted an example. The ID's are the ID's associated on the data-side.

Comment: @Fluidbyte Right, look at the fiddles i just added, they show that when using an object, the sort order gets changed, but when using an array, it keeps the same sort order.

Comment: +1 - as sorting on the server, if available, is a clean option. However, I would use `[[490, "A"], ..]` or `[{id: 490, val: "A"}, ..]` because 490 really isn't functioning as a key here.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var output = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

var options = [];
$.each(output, function(key, value) {
    options.push(
        $("<option>").val(key).text(value)
    );
});

options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.text() > b.text();
});
```

Comment: `sort` should should return an integer not a boolean (though a boolean does work in FF at least), so make it `a.text() - b.text()` to work in more browsers.